# bootstrapDialog is failing with querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-dialog

I am getting the following error with bootstrapDialog. I am just initializing the bootStrapDialog i.e. BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');

Can anyone help me on how to resolve?

Browser throws the error as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.querySelector is not a function
at n.Modal (modal.js:80)
at new n (bootstrap-dialog.min.js:1)
at o.realize (bootstrap-dialog.min.js:1)
at open (bootstrap-dialog.min.js:1)
at Function.o.alert (bootstrap-dialog.min.js:1)
```

bootstrap:

```
bootstrap-4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js
```

bootstrap3-dialog:

```
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [*Writing the perfect question*](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). We can't help you with code we can't see. It sounds as though you're trying to call a Bootstrap dialog method on an element that doesn't exist, but it's hard to say more than that...

Comment: I am getting the querySelection not a function error in the browser, while initializing the bootstrapDialog initialization and calling alert the function.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Quite confusing.

Comment: @Ramana were you able to fix this issue? I'm still stuck with this.

Answer (score 5):

I hit this issue as a result of updating to bootstrap 4 but retaining bootstrap3-dialog. [boostrap4-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap4-dialog) appears to fix the issue.

Comment: still not sure on how to use what you suggest, could you please provide an example, perhaps a JSFiddle ?

Comment: @Somebody are you using bootstrap 4 and bootstrap3-dialog together? If so upgrade to bootstrap4-dialog. It's not really something that can be demonstrated in a fiddle.

Comment: Do you know if there's any `cdn` for this version?

Comment: I don't. I would have used npm. But of we've just dropped the dependency now entirely.